# Module wise development in Java

Tags: java, architecture, module, package

I am about to develop a Java desktop application, which I would like to keep it in module wise, so it is easy for me to customize. For an example, let's take a billing system. Right now I can divide it to few modules

1. Accounting
2. Billing
3. Print Bill
4. Email Bill

If someone told me "I don't need to print the Bill", then I can remove the "Print Bill" module and so on.

I have seen in some applications (C++) where they have been developed as seperate applications and combined together somehow.

In Java, what is the best way of module wise development? The best way I know is creating packages and managing things via interfaces.

Whatever it is, the main advantage would be minimizing the effort when customizations appear. What are the suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A naive approach would be to only use packages to functionally partition your code. You also want your packages to have as few dependencies as possible. Any shared dependencies should be "moved up" in an other package like "core" or something else that would be a dependency of all the packages that need it.

A quick example based on yours :

- package client would make it possible to manipulate clients
- package accounting would handle client account information and depend on client
- package  billing would handle billing and depend on client (or accounting?)
- package billing.receipt would handle receipt generation and depend on billing (and indirectly on client)
- package billing.receipt.printing would handle receipt printing and depend on billing.receipt (and indirectly on billing and client)
- package billing.receipt.email would handle receipt email sending and depend on billing.receipt (and indirectly on billing and client)

For a more industrial version, you should separate your code into different java projects with interdependencies that you could build into a single application with a tool like Maven. The packages separation would still hold, but using different projects and a formal build process would help enforcing weak-coupling.

Comment: Seems like a good answer. Can you explain bit further?

Comment: For an example, if I take the accounting package, should I move my "Billing" package or keep it under "UI' package?

Comment: @Tracer I have no idea what your UI package refer to, but if it's User Interface it seems inappropriate

Comment: @Tracer edited my answer further to add information about industrialization.

Comment: The user interface should be in the main program, isnt it?

Comment: @Tracer Not necessarly, it could be one or multiple additionnal modules (a separate one for each functionnal module + a core one for general templates?). It really depends on how you want your application to function, but you could imagine sending receipt emails in batch without the need for a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Answering a question for "best way" is hard, because you could only answer it with "it depends" - on the specific circumstances as well as the opinion of the developer.

What I would suggest you to do is take an approach that defines clear interfaces between modules and maybe split them into separate jars. This allows you to hide the implementation details in the abstraction of the interface and you do not need to care about that but only call the correct interface.

Also for high customisation I'd favor "configuration over code" which means that you select the used modules by configuration and not by deploying specific binaries. Again with separate jars both is possible.

So I think your idea of using different packages and interfaces seems very valid to me. Maybe I'd pack them to different jars or use them depending on the configuration.

I think using a bunch of different executables and connect them by pipelining them is also an option, but I somehow dislike it, because it adds increased effort in handling the communication between different executables. This is an unnecessary overload when your application is handling it "all in one".

Comment: The user interface should be in the main program, isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

Separate the parts into artifacts, built into numerous `jar`s. Hide everything behind interfaces. Then have an "application" project using all needed artifacts and integrating them together. Use dependency management tool like Maven or Gradle to build it all together, and Spring to integrate the modules in the resulting application.

For a desktop application, you may want to use some platform like [Eclipse RCP](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI) or [Netbeans RCP](https://netbeans.org/features/platform/) - they have each their own plugin system and dependency injection / integration frameworks.

Comment: This is a desktop application. what about ui? it is also built into another package?

Comment: I think User Interface we cant do that

Comment: Edited to add possible ways to create modularized desktop GUI application. Or you can use the first approach and make your GUI application the integrating module.